# HaProxy forward proxy works on HTTP but gives 503 on HTTPS

Tags: docker, haproxy

I'm expecting the following config to receive HTTPS requests, do the SSL offloading and send HTTP requests to my backends, however with HTTPS I get "503 service unavailable".

- all ACLs work correctly on HTTP and the stats page shows them as online
- The stats page works correctly on HTTPS
- These are all in a docker compose file, docker is doing the name resolution to internal IP correctly

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious? Quite new to attempting this so any help is appreciated.

```
global
  tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
  mode http
  timeout connect 5000ms                  
  timeout client 50000ms                   
  timeout server 50000ms                   

backend certbot
  option httpchk GET /
  default-server init-addr libc,none
  server certbot_server certbot check port 80

backend client
  option httpchk HEAD /
  server client_server client check port 80

backend api               
  option httpchk OPTIONS /api/healthcheck
  server api_server api check port 80

frontend app
  bind *:80
  bind *:443 ssl crt /certs/productpedia.co.uk.pem

  use_backend certbot if { path_beg -i /.well-known/acme-challenge/ }                    
  use_backend api if { path_beg /api }
  default_backend client

  stats enable
  stats uri /stats
  stats refresh 10s
  stats admin if LOCALHOST
```

EDIT:

Attached a wireshark trace of the the 503 request, looks like server is resetting the connection, but not sure where I can go from here, or what would be causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a full day of debugging, it looks like simply specifying port 80 did the trick, although I would have expected the default port to be 80 perhaps it carries through a default port of 443? I could also get rid of the port 80 after check after this change which was the original trigger hint that something might be off there.

```
backend certbot
  option httpchk GET /
  default-server init-addr libc,none
  server certbot_server certbot:80 check

backend client
  option httpchk HEAD /
  server client_server client:80 check

backend api               
  option httpchk OPTIONS /api/healthcheck
  server api_server api:80 check
```